# Как изменять переменные из функции main в других функциях?

Tags: java

```
class Main1{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;
    one_to_two(two);
    System.out.print(one + " " + two);
}
public static void one_to_two(int two){
    int one = two;
}
}
```

Хочу, чтобы переменная one приняла значение two в теле не основной функции. В с++ на это есть указатели. А как это сделать в Java?

Comment: Никак. Область видимости переменных, созданных в функции, ограничена этой функцией. Создавайте переменные в самом классе.

Comment: По ссылке можно передать обьект и менять его состояние, например какой нибудь `AtomicInteger`

Answer (score 2):

В Java нет указателей. Такой трюк не получится. Все примитивы можно сказать что дублируются при передаче их в качестве параметров. Они находятся в стэке исполнения и менять их можно только на их уровне стэка

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```java
class Main1 {
    static int one;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        one = 1;
        int two = 2;
        one_to_two(two);
        System.out.print(one + " " + two);
    }
    public static void one_to_two(int two){
        one = two;
    }
}
```

То есть переменную `one` нужно вынести в область видимости, доступную для обоих методов.

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую - никак. Локальные переменные, объявленные в одной функции только в ней и видны, указателей в java нет.
Но можно сделать опосредованно.

**1) Через массивы**

```
public static void one_to_two(int[] data, int two){
    data[0] = two;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] one = new int[0];
    int two = 2;
    one_to_two(one, two);
    System.out.print(one[0] + " " + two);
}
```

**2) Через вспомогательные классы**

```
class Main1{
    class DataHolder {
       int one;
    }
    public static void one_to_two(DataHolder data, int two){
        int one = two;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataHolder data = new DataHolder();
        data.one = 1;
        int two = 2;
        one_to_two(data, two);
        System.out.print(data.one + " " + two);
    }
}
```